# NoClassDefFoundError while running the spring application in command prompt

Tags: java, spring, exception

Below is my Spring code. When I tried to compile the program all the classes have been successfully compiled and while running the program `NoClassDefFoundError` arose.

**MainMethodCLass:**

```
package test;

import beans.SpringTest;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory;
public class Client
{
  public static void main(String [] raja)
  {
    //find xml
    Resource r = new ClassPathResource("resources/spring.xml");
    //load xml into container
    BeanFactory fact = new XmlBeanFactory(r);

    //create test class object
    Object o = fact.getBean("t");
    SpringTest t = (SpringTest)o;
    t.hello();
  }
}
```

**Simple POJO class:**

```
package beans;
public class SpringTest
{
  public void hello()
  {
      System.out.println("Hello World");
  }
}
```

**spring.xml File in package resources:**

```
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN 2.0//EN"
  "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans-2.0.dtd">

<beans>
 <bean id = "t" class = "beans.Test">
 </bean>

</beans>
```

When I had compiled this program it has been successfully compiled, but when I am compiling the following error was raised:

```
D:\Corejava>java test.Client
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/io/Resource
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.io.Resource
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 6 more
```

Comment: No I didn't use Maven @Abdelhak

Comment: what is the the content of your lib folder after you build the project ?

Comment: @RafikBELDI I am not using any IDE simply I downloaded the jar files and set the class path for the jars and want to execute in command prompt.The program is compiling but it is not executing.

Answer (score 0):

Add your spring libraries to your classpath

command line should be

```
>java -classpath <all the libraries jars here> test.Client
```

Answer (score 0):

You have more than one `org.springframework.core` in your path with different versions. remove one , use `maven` to download dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You need to  includ jar `spring-core-*.jar` file in your class path and lib folder.
In your calss do this `import org.springframework.core.*` is all in the core jar file.

Answer (score 0):

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError - This error does not mean that the JVM cannot find your class file in class path. Either It finds the class but the referred class must be referring some dependent classes which are not loaded, or there are more than one definition. Use Maven to load the Spring lib.